# Understanding play/scala error handling

Tags: scala, error-handling, playframework-2.0, try-catch

I have a web application in Scala/Play with Cassandra as the database. I ran into following issue while testing for potential errors.

Below are the components of my project

1. Application.scala -> Basic controller
2. Model.scala -> Holds the
       business logic
3. CassandraClient.scala -> Logic to connect to
       cassandra and run query on cassandra

CassandraClient.scala looks like below

```
object CassandraClient {

private val cluster = Cluster.builder()
    .withLoadBalancingPolicy(
      new WhiteListPolicy(new RoundRobinPolicy(), nodes))
    .withSocketOptions(socketOptions)
    .addContactPointsWithPorts(nodes)
    .withCredentials(CASSANDRA_USERNAME, CASSANDRA_PWD).build()
}

 private val session = cluster.connect()

def getValueFromCassandraTable(token:String) = {
 var query = QueryBuilder.select.all()...
 seesion.execute(query)
}
```

The Cassandra connection is first established when i call getValueFromCassandraTable the first time. And since CassandraClient is an Object, the logic to connect to Cassandra only gets called once.

Model.Scala has some code to handle future returned by session.execute.

For eg: Look at sample code below in Model.scala.

```
    def getTitles(titles: String)(implicit ctxt: ExecutionContext): Future[List[<Sometype>]] = {
        try{
            CassandraClient.getValueFromCassandraTable(token).toScalaFuture.map { rows =>
                  rows.map(row => row("value").toList
                }.recover { case e: Exception =>List()}
              }
        } catch{case e:Exception => 
           Logger.info("THIS DOES NOT EXECUTE??")
           Future{List()}}
    }
```

Now when the above sample code gets executed the first time, session.execute(), gets executed. And then getValueFromCassandraTable is executed.
So i thought that the flow of execution is 
Code snippet above in Models.scala -> session.execute() -> getValueFromCassandraTable()

So, if session.execute fails, i should be able to capture it in try catch exception block. But to my surprise catch block is not executed when session.execute fails. Instead play framework throws an exception. Can someone explain this behavior.

Exception Stack

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anon$1.apply(Action.scala:498) ~[play_2.10-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:105) ~[play_2.10-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:105) ~[play_2.10-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21) ~[play_2.10-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Action.scala:104) ~[play_2.10-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Action.scala:103) ~[play_2.10-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) ~[scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Action.scala:103) ~[play_2.10-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Action.scala:96) ~[play_2.10-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.DoneIteratee$$anonfun$mapM$2.apply(Iteratee.scala:741) ~[play-iteratees_2.10-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at models.Model$.getTitles(Model.scala:121) ~[classes/:na]
    at models.Model$.getMatchingTitles(Model.scala:48) ~[classes/:na]
    at models.Model$.getMatchingTitles(Model.scala:56) ~[classes/:na]
    at controllers.Application$$anonfun$searchTitle$1.apply(Application.scala:15) ~[classes/:na]
    at controllers.Application$$anonfun$searchTitle$1.apply(Application.scala:15) ~[classes/:na]
    at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anonfun$async$1.apply(Action.scala:456) ~[play_2.10-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anonfun$async$1.apply(Action.scala:456) ~[play_2.10-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$.invokeBlock(Action.scala:533) ~[play_2.10-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$.invokeBlock(Action.scala:530) ~[play_2.10-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anon$1.apply(Action.scala:493) ~[play_2.10-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.AuthenticationException: Authentication error on host /10.65.5.44:9042: Username and/or password are incorrect
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$8.apply(Connection.java:368) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.6.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$8.apply(Connection.java:338) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.6.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$ChainingListenableFuture.run(Futures.java:861) ~[guava-16.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:297) ~[guava-16.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.executeListener(ExecutionList.java:156) ~[guava-16.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.execute(ExecutionList.java:145) ~[guava-16.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.set(AbstractFuture.java:185) ~[guava-16.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Future.onSet(Connection.java:1170) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.6.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Connection.java:1000) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.6.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Connection.java:922) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.6.jar:na]
```

Lin# 121 in Modle.scala is the one which calls CassandrClient.getValueFromCassandraTable. 
I am mimicking the exception by passing a wrong password connecting to cassandra, hence getting AuthroizationException. I expect this exception to be caught in Try catch. But it is not caught.

(Note that this is has nothing to do with Future, as session.executAysnc is not even called when the exception occurs. So futures have yet not come into play.)

--EDIT--

Looks like Play is swallowing Exception and throwing an Error object. Not sure why is that happening.

Comment: This question seems to be purely about understanding of Futures in Scala.

Comment: well, i am not sure about that.  exception is thrown at session.execute() which is not a asynchronous call. what i dont understand is why my try catch block does not catch exception thrown by session.execute.

Comment: Does it get caught if you use `recover {case _ => Future(List())}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have [InterruptedException](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8938)

For example code dont print "InterruptedException test" if you dont use Await.

```
 try {
   val exception = Future {
     throw new InterruptedException("exception")
   }.recover { case e: Exception => "ok" }

  exception.onComplete {
    case Success(a) => println(a)
    case Failure(err) => println(err)
  }
  //Await.result(exception, 1 seconds) 

 } catch {
   case e: Exception => println("InterruptedException test")
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

session.execute() could fail with the error like IOError. And you catch only Exception.

[image: Exception hierarchy]

Check if you got no error, just trivial exception. Would be nice if you will add stack trace to your question.

You can try to catch any Throwable (do not do it in real project, you can try it only for the debug)

```
try {
  .... your code ...
} catch {
  case _ => errorHandler(e)
}
```

it will not catch error only in the case if it in the Future.

**EDIT:**

Live example on my cassandra database. 
It shows a list of users or "something going wrong" string in the case of exception during connection to the cassandra. For example wrong node or cassandra is shutting down.

```
    package controllers

    import com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster
    import com.datastax.driver.core.Session
    import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

    import play.api._
    import play.api.mvc._

    class Application extends Controller {

      def index = Action {
        try{
          var b = new StringBuilder
          for (row <- CassandraClient.getValueFromCassandraTable()) {
            b ++= row.getString("user_id")
            b ++= "\n"
          }
          Ok(b.toString())
        } catch {
          case _ => InternalServerError("something going wrong")
        }
      }

    }

    object CassandraClient {
       private val cluster = Cluster.builder()
        .addContactPoint("localhost")
        .withPort(9042)
        .build()

      val session = cluster.connect()

      def getValueFromCassandraTable() = {
        session.execute("SELECT * FROM mykeyspace.users")
      }
    }
```

Comment: yes you are right.  Play throws  ExceptionInInitializerError , which is then caught by try catch block. However, i am confused by such behavior. My code throws AuthenticationException of type DriverException. Play seems to be catching it throwing ExceptionInInitializerError. Any explanation on whats happening? I posted the stack track.

Comment: this string "private val session = cluster.connect()" is not in your try-catch block.  AuthenticationException throws when you call "cluster.connect()". It's not handled by your code, so play take it an wrap in "ExceptionInInitializerError". I suppose you run this code directly at play start.

Comment: Hmm,  cluster.connect() is defined in the body of object CassandraClient. So i believe it is only called when CassandraClient is referenced the first time. Since this is  a play app. It is only getting called when i make the first httpcall to my service.

Comment: are you sure you do not call "CassandraClient" in any other place before this ? Maybe it's called within some "framework" ? What about cluster configuration - socketOptions, nodes - how it happens that they are defined ?

Comment: yes  i am not calling CassandraClient anywhere else. cluster configuration- socketoptions, nodes etc are defined in the CassandraClient object. I have omitted that code from the snippet above.

Comment: look at my EDIT addition to the answer. I am pretty sure you initialise session out of try catch block (or you do not catch correct error in that block)